# Is the mean center of the vertices of a convex polygon always inside the polygon?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, polygons

As simple as that. I'm doing an R program where I need to order clockwise a bunch of points that describe a regular polygon and to do that I figured I could find a point inside, change to polar coordinates and calculate the angle, but I don't know if the mean of the vertices always gives a point inside the polygon.

Any help? I would appreciate a demonstration if possible.

Comment: Simply use induction, adding vertices 1 by 1.

Comment: Yes it is always inside. The mean of all vertices is a convex combination of the vertices, and the (convex) polygon itself is the set of all convex combinations of its vertices.